# UWP Unit Test App Blank

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've created a UWP Unit Test App in the past and remember it working fine.
I just tried to create a new one from scratch and hit F5 (no references, one empty test method) - out of box template.
I get a successful compile and launch, however the app window is empty and does not present the UWP testing UI.

Is this a known issue, or some basic prerequisite I've overlooked?

I'm running Visual Studio 15.5.5 on Windows 10 1709 (16299.192)

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unit Test App should not be launched directly, instead it should run through the `Test Explorer`. In **Test** menu, choose **Windows**, and then choose **Test Explorer**.  In the **Unit Test Explorer** window click **Run all**. This should execute all your tests. For more information follow the [walkthrough here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-windows-store-apps).

Comment: Great thanks, that seems to work. Did something change, because I thought I remembered needing to run the app? And there was UI stating that tests are running, etc.

Comment: I thought it was always like this... But I can't say for sure :-D

Comment: Is there a way to do unit test without starting a test app?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as far as I am aware, the Unit test app must run in order to run the tests